# How to use a user defined config variable as module name in @testable import in a swift test?

Tags: swift, xctest

I have a user defined variable "MODULE_NAME_WITH_SUFFIX" that is different in every schema.

Now I need to import this module name in my tests, but don't know how.

Before I had a simple import:

```
@testable import MyApp
```

Now I want to use something like:

```
@testable import $(MODULE_NAME_WITH_SUFFIX)
```

Is this possible in Swift somehow?

Probably not, but is it maybe possible to import the module later programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far only this worked:

In the Build settings of your project go to Active Compilation Conditions and add these fields to the schemes.

Create one unique variable in each schema config:

```
# in debug scheme 1
DEBUG ABC_SCHEMA_ACTIVE

# in debug scheme 2
DEBUG XYZ_SCHEMA_ACTIVE

# in debug scheme 3
DEBUG

# in release scheme 1
ABC_SCHEMA_ACTIVE

# in release scheme 2
XYZ_SCHEMA_ACTIVE

# in release scheme 3
< nothing >
```

No need to set a value for it, with #if you cannot compare the value.

In the Build settings of the Test-Target you can use the MODULE_NAME_WITH_SUFFIX like this:

```
# before
TEST_HOST = "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/MyApp";

# after
TEST_HOST = "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(MODULE_NAME_WITH_SUFFIX).app/$(MODULE_NAME_WITH_SUFFIX)";
```

Then in every class derived from XCTestCase, instead of the normal import you add this monster:

```
#if ABC_SCHEMA_ACTIVE
    @testable import MyAppABCSuffix
#elseif XYZ_SCHEMA_ACTIVE
    @testable import MyAppXYZSuffix
#else
    @testable import MyApp
#endif
```

Happy testing!

Comment: Worked like a dream for me.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible in Swift. You can however do this in Objective-C using the preprocessor as the actual header name will be substituted in at compile time. The would of course require you to write your tests in Objective-C, though.

Comment: And maybe write Swift tests that import a module that is in Objective-C and which imports the dynamic module name?

Comment: Hmm a little convoluted, but could potentially work, would be interested to hear the results if you try it!

Comment: Didn't really work out, but I found a solution that is okayish for now .. thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the `canImport` as a conditional.

```
#if canImport(MyApp)
    @testable import MyApp
#endif

#if canImport(MyApp_Dev)
    @testable import MyApp_Dev
#endif
```